# How to add Bugzilla-bug-version to SVN commit description?

Tags: eclipse, svn, bugzilla, mylyn

I'm using: Eclipse Juno with Mylyn, SVN Subversive Plugin, Bugzilla 4.2.4.

I strive for the overall goal to loosly relate SVN commits with bugzilla tasks. Thanks to Mylyn I retrieve a great deal of information ready to be attached to the commit description. Good so far.

However, I wish to add the version that a bug is related to, to the commit description. In Eclipse, we may add task variables (Window, Preferences, Mylyn, Team, Commit Comment Templates). By default there is: ${task.status} - ${connector.task.prefix} ${task.key}: ${task.description} 
${task.url}

Unfortunately there is no such thing like ${task.version}. Is there a workaround to add the Bugzilla version of the bug to the commit description?

thanks heaps,